# Which jobs involve math but can be done without using the internet?

Tags: career-development

After a long struggle with focusing in my mathematical studies I found out that if I use the Internet very irregular, like once every 4 days, I can be productive and enjoy mathematics.

My question is are there jobs involving mathematics out there were I only have to use the Internet very irregular? I hope you can answer my question!

Comment: A helpful detail would be knowing what type of math you are studying, at what level, what areas of math do you enjoy the most etc. More details about your interests and expertise will help people think of what jobs might be relevant to you.

Comment: You can be productive and enjoy yourself doing maths using the Internet as well !?!

Comment: No, I can`t I get very distracted when using the Internet and get a severe form of ADD. Currently I`m doing a master of mathematics with a specialization in stochastics. I enjoy the more fundamental parts of stochastics and I like programming but my mind just stops with thinking when I get overburdened by the incestant stream of information.

Comment: What about teaching ?

Comment: That is not really an option I`m willing to consider. I would love to use my mathematical knowledge in industry or in academia. I like to tutor, but I don`t like the prospective of having to teach kids that don`t want to be taught and the lack of growth potential in that function.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have become a world of Big Data and the Internet is the medium for information overload. This is also true in Mathematics, so I suggest you figure out how to deal within those constraints or lack thereof!

Comment: The annoying thing is, is that I have this problem already for a very long time, even in high school! Because of this I started meditating a lot, but my mind has trouble focusing when using the Internet for hard intellectual work even though I meditate a lot. Why I`m asking this question on Math.stackexchange is that I need to know if I can continue this lifestyle well into my career without cutting out too many options.

Answer (score 1):

If you enjoy mathematics, you might consider becoming a mathematics teacher. I don't think that requires regular use of the Internet. Your ability to focus on and enjoy mathematics for itself would be good for students, at least some of them, and even a few responsive students can make teaching a pretty satisfying occupation.

Comment: You are right, I will consider this. The thing is just that I love to learn, but I get really overwhelmed with information when I have to use the Internet.